# Access Database Always "Compacts on Close" - Why?

Tags: ms-access

I have set my Access Database's "Compact on Close" setting off. I've done this because we have relatively high network traffic - but utilize a "local front end system". From this, it is rarely necessary to compact our network copy.

However, even though I have the "Compact on Close" setting in "Current Database" set to false, it still does. Why does this happen?

My Setup:

A front-end and back-end are housed on a server. When the user opens the front-end via the server, a copy of itself is made to the user's desktop ("local copy"). This is the copy they will now use. It is still linked to the same back-end file which is located on the server.

Comment: Can you take a look at the vba project? Maybe there is a call to compact on the database close event.

Comment: @JulianKuchlbauer Yes, I checked through the entire project and couldn't find anything that switched it to "true". Very odd.

Comment: You use a front end system? Is the setting checked at the backend database?

Comment: @JulianKuchlbauer no it is not

Comment: Is the local frontend compacted, or the network backend?

Comment: @Andre The network front end is compacted.

Comment: I thought you used a **local** frontend? What then is the "network frontend"? Or maybe I misunderstood - is your database [split](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-an-Access-database-3015ad18-a3a1-4e9c-a7f3-51b1d73498cc)?

Comment: @Andre Yes, my database is split. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: ... then which is it? Perhaps add a short description of your setup to your question.

Comment: @Andre Added it! Sorry for late reply - been swamped with chores.

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting in Access Options/Current Database.  Uncheck it and it should stop.

http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/compact/compact-on-close.html